# what is the difference between margin-left and left, in my code margin-left:90px moves my box but left does not move the box

Tags: css

I have box1 and I test with margin-left och left. margin-left can move the box but nothing happens with left:90px.what is exactly the difference between these two?

```
#box1 {
    width: 250px;
   padding: 25px;
   border: 15px solid;
  top:30px;
 //margin-left:90px;
left:90px;
```

}

```css
#box1 {
        width: 250px;
       padding: 25px;
       border: 15px solid;
      top:30px;
     margin-left:90px;
    //left:90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">

Box1
</div>
```

Comment: you need position:relative to use left

Comment: `left` requires a **positioning context**

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left` adds a margin to the left of the element.

`left` changes an element's position and can only be used in conjunction with the `position` attribute, or rather, it is inconsequential when used with the default `position: static` value.

```css
p
{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>I have a margin</p>
<div>I'm positioned with left</div>
```

Comment: Thanks David! As I see : margin-left, margin-righ etc  can be used for all positions but  left, right, top .. can be used for position absolute?